# How to determine if C/C++ function or macro parameter is a constant string?

Tags: c++

I want to define a macro or function with one input parameter x, is there a way to detect if the input parameter is a constant string or a variable? For example SOME_MACRO(x):

```
#define SOME_MACRO(x) \
   // if x is a constant string \
   printf("x is a constant string"); \
   // else \
   printf("x is a variable");


   SOME_MACRO("This is a constant string");  // it detects x is a constant string

   int x = 2;
   std::string y = std::to_string(x);
   SOME_MACRO(y)    // it detects y is not a constant string
```

Comment: It really depends what you mean by constant string. This seems like a XY problem. If you share why you believe you need to know this, we may be able to provide you with an alternative solution.

Comment: why macro? Write two overloads one for constant the other for non-const strings

Comment: `#define SOME_MACRO(x) "" x ""` will cause a compiler error if `x` isn't a C-string literal.

Comment: Du you mean a `const` string or a string literal?

Comment: This is another reason not to use MACROs.  Use inline functions instead.  Although, we've had a hard time convincing 3rd party software people to use inline functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking for a macro because you don't know any C++ feature that can do it and are searching for a solution outside of C++? In that case, you can do it in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(const std::string& s){
    std::cout << "is constant\n";
}
void foo(std::string& s){
    std::cout << "is not constant\n";
}
int main() {
    std::string x = "asdasd";
    foo(x);
    foo("asdasdasd");
}
```

Are you asking for a macro for a different reason? Then the answer is the same ;). Don't use a macro.

If you want to detect string literals, thats not possible, as you cannot distinguish them from arrays of `const char`. Though you can add an overload that matches string literals and arrays of `const char`:

```
template <size_t N>
void foo(const char(&s)[N]) {
    std::cout << "array of const char\n";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MKjfMcjfv)

Comment: Note that this also marks `const std::string x` as "constant" even though it is a variable, not sure that is what OP wants since their wording is ambiguous.

Comment: @Quimy it's a constant variable :P

Comment: Yea, exactly :D So not sure which of "constant string or a variable" it should count